# C++ caching vector empty()

Tags: c++

Does it make sense to cache `vector.empty()` value?

```
Vector<X> list;
...
if(!list.empty()){          // cmp + jnz
   ...
   // some heavy calculations
   ...
   list.pop_back();
}
```

vs

```
Vector<X> list;
bool list_empty;
...
if(!list_empty){            // jnz
   ...
   // some heavy calculations
   ...
   list.pop_back();
   list_empty = list.empty();   // cmp
}
```

Where

```
bool List::empty(){
  return last_ptr == first_ptr;         // implementation from gcc's std
}
```

I think it is better to cache, because in cases when list is not empty, it will take just 1 op to compare. Plus to `cmp`, it should fetch two values form memory, while for `jnz`, only one.

P.S. Vector is just a good example. This logic can appear in another cases.

Comment: This will make less of a difference than a fly farting on your CPU at the right time.

Comment: You mention a `vector`, but use a `List`. Which one is it?

Comment: If you call empty after popping on the list, I don't understand the point of caching it, as it's different each time you call it.

Comment: All standard containers but `std::forward_list` have constant time `size()` and therefore also `empty()`.

Comment: @NeilKirk in cases if it will be empty - it will just `jnz`, not `jnz`+`cmp`

Comment: @tower120 if "some heavy calculations" are really that heavy then you won't notice anything. 1 asm instruction is nothing. Further more, are you comparing debug or release build?

Comment: @NeilKirk Now that I rather should ask - "does it faster to compare bool and update that bool if true/false, or just compare two ints?"

Comment: No idea. And it depends on so many things. And the compiler may generate assembly different to what you expected, especially when optimizing. The only way to know is to time it. And that's only true for that compiler. Trust me, this kind of thing has 1% chance of making any difference to your performance.

Answer (score 8):

Given modern aggressive compiler optimisations one really shouldn't waste time worrying about such trivialities, but if you *must*: run each version through a profiler and see for yourself which is faster and by how much.

Comment: +1 Agree and even if profiling you see you gain 10 us then you'd better **spend time to optimize something else** keeping your code as much readable as possible (otherwise **why you program in C++?!**).

Comment: +1, this is the only correct answer. If the code is *so* performance critical that saving a comparison could matter, its writing *must* be profiling-driven anyway.

Comment: Isn't there some kind of idiom for cases like this? And what compiler can do with this? It just inline that empty() for me, that's all. Plus when I write this, I more concern about that for CPU it is easier to predict `jnz` operation than `cmp`+`jnz`.

Comment: @tower120 it will inline but it'll also reorder instructions, remove parameters, reuse registers for last_ptr and first_ptr and many other things. More we write _clever_ code without exactly knowing what's going on all around and more we make this task harder for him. Such microptimizations 99.9999% won't affect generated code (or they'll even make it worse).

Comment: BTW if (!list_empty) WILL generate a CMP (or equivalent) because it's a test...you save time because you do not read two value in memory (pointers) but comparison must be done (can you assert ZF will be set by last instruction before JNZ?). Moreover probably that pointers may also be in a register because used before so. Only honest advice I may give about this topic: DO NOT ASSUME YOU CAN DO SUCH MICROPTIMIZATIONS BETTER THAN COMPILER. YOU DON'T. If it's a measured time critical point you'd better take a look to generated assembly code first.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti optimize it or not, but there is two instructions that should be executed, against one. `!list_empty` will never generate cmp, it is bool.

Comment: @tower120: You are worrying far too much about optimization there: C++ is not assembler, the compiler has far too many optimization possibilites to quantify the speed difference between such miniscule bits of expressions.

Comment: @tower120 it won't generate CMP (1/3 cycles) but MOVZX + TEST (1/3 cycles as CMP). It may be omitted if and only if previous instruction will leave ZF usable by JNZ.  As comparison the other way it may generate MOV + CMP (but with two accesses to memory). **BUT** let me stress that it'll also optimize code for pipeline and for code around that jump. Really...don't assume such simple optimizations are useful. It will do better than you (and stable across architectures). In the time you write one line of code it'll perform optimizations you'll calculate in DAYS. Do you want to compete?

Answer (score 1):

All standard containers but `std::forward_list` have constant time `size()` and therefore also `empty()` (`std::forward_list` only has constant cost `empty()`).

So, caching either yourself has a negative (or at least no positive) influence on performance.

**Do not forget the "as-if"-rule and its exceptions**: As long as the compiled program has the same observable behavior for any defined behavior (or the change is covered by an exception), the compiler can do any transformation it wants.

Anyway, if **after measuring** you have determined where your code is too slow, first try better algorithms, and then measure each "optimization" you try.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty well known that one memory fetch is faster than two, regardless of cache or not.  I can also almost guarantee that `last_ptr` and `first_ptr are` not in registers for any program larger than 10 lines.

Your `if(!list_empty)` may be twice as fast as `if(!list_empty())`. If you apply that to your entire program, it means twice as long battery life on your phone, or half as many servers in your data center, etc :)

But of course you need to think of the number of `pop_back()` calls (which will be slower) compared to the number of `if(!list_empty)` (which will be faster).

Comment: But does it store list_empty in cache, than? I don't think so. And if last_ptr and first_ptr will be in one cache line (16 bytes), than they will be gathered in one fetch, not in two.